# Abel inversion where axisymmetric function is multiplied by $\sin(\phi)$

Tags: integration

I have a problem seems similar to Abel inversion, but the axisymmetric function is multiplied by $\cos{\phi}$, making the integrand non-axisymmetric. Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: Abel inversion problem]

Each chord is at a position $y$ and gives me a number $F(y)$ where

$$F(y) = \int^{+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}_{-\sqrt{a^2-y^2}} f(R) \sin(\phi) dx$$

I would like to invert the equation to get $f(R)$.

Answer (score 0):

Change of variables:
$$F(y) = 2\int_{y}^{a} f(R) \frac{R\sin(\phi)}{(R^2-y^2)^{1/2}}dR$$
Note that $R\sin(\phi)=y$. Substitute this in, take $y$ out of the integral and rewrite as a new function of y:
$$G(y) = \frac{F(y)}{y} = 2\int_{y}^{a} \frac{f(R)}{(R^2-y^2)^{1/2}}dR$$
It's ok to take $y$ out because it's basically a constant since it is a parameter of $G$. Define a new function $\gamma(R) = f(R)/R$ and substitute this in:
$$G(y) = 2\int_{y}^{a} \frac{\gamma(R)R}{(R^2-y^2)^{1/2}}dR$$
This is the usual Abel inversion form, which gives
$$\gamma(R) = -\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{R}^{a} \frac{dG}{dy} \frac{1}{(y^2-R^2)^{1/2}}dy$$
The answer is then
$$f(R) = -\frac{R}{\pi} \int_{R}^{a} \frac{dG}{dy} \frac{1}{(y^2-R^2)^{1/2}}dy$$